# How to make 2 fixed button without overlapping them when reducing the window size

Tags: html, css

Ive got 2 fixed buttons but when I reduce the size of my window they go one on top of the other.

This is my code:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab" style="display:flex;position: fixed;z-index:23232;top: 89%;margin-right: 3%; color:white;left: 82%;height:7.6%; width:3%;background-color:rgb(0,162,77);"
    (click)="onButtonClicked($event)" *ngIf="createPermission!==false">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>

<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab" style="display:flex;position: fixed;z-index:34344;top: 89%;color:white;left: 87%;height:7.6%; width:3%; background-color:rgb(0,162,77);"
    (click)="getProspect($event)">
    <i class="material-icons">get_app</i>
</button>
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: are those buttons in the same div?

Comment: Yes they are on the same div

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the fact that they don't overlap by going one down the other?

Comment: That could solve the problem but I was asked to make the 2 buttons close to each other so i cant modify the layout

Comment: If you can post the whole html + css we can try to do something. I don't like the `top:89%`, and other few things. But I can't really help you since I don't know the father gerarchy of their div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the exact problem you gave us too little information. (I think you use material design buttons)

But assuming your buttons haven't an extra wrapper element with a fixed width (e.g. px) all the percentages in your styles could cause problems.

If the positioning (like `left: 87%`) dependents on your screen width it will change on resize. Because of the `fixed` position the elements are removed from the normal document flow and can overlap.

To fix the problem you could make a wrapper div.
This way the wrapper has the fixed position and the buttons are independent of the screen width. See the code snipped.

```css
button.mdl-button{
  color:white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color:rgb(0,162,77);
}

button.first{
  z-index:23232;
}
button.sec{
   z-index:34344;
}

.wrapper{
  left: 82%;
  background: red;
  display:flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab first"
    (click)="onButtonClicked($event)" *ngIf="createPermission!==false">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>

<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab sec"
    (click)="getProspect($event)">
    <i class="material-icons">get_app</i>
</button>

</div>
```

I separated the css from the html and added a wrapper div as described above and
I replaced some `percentages` by `px` as well.
This way you have a little bit more control over the positioning and the size of the buttons.

Hopefully this fixes your problem.